# QGIS Processing algorithm output

Tags: python, qgis

I am developing a plugin in QGIS using Python language. This plugin uses algorithms from Processing Toolbox and I save some results in the temporary folder assigning "QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT" in the output field of each algorithm. However my plugin is just working well when I return the temporary folder directory using QMessageBox. If I do not use this, my plugin does not work, so nothing is saved in the temporary folder. Why this happens?

Example of code working:

```
clip_ndvi = Processing.runAlgorithm("saga:cliprasterwithpolygon", {
                            'INPUT': str(self.dlg.lineEdit.text()),
                            'POLYGONS': vl,
                            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT})
                        out_ndvi = clip_ndvi['OUTPUT']
                        QMessageBox.about(self.dlg,'teste', str(out_ndvi))
```

Example of code not working:

```
clip_ndvi = Processing.runAlgorithm("saga:cliprasterwithpolygon", {
                            'INPUT': str(self.dlg.lineEdit.text()),
                            'POLYGONS': vl,
                            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT})
                        out_ndvi = clip_ndvi['OUTPUT']
```

The difference is in the QMessageBox.

Comment: Hello, I think you should post some sourcecode(simplified), and describe method which you use to install plugin. Do you get any error, stacktrace or logs?

Comment: Thanks @404pio. I edit the question adding some code. The plugin is correctly installed because it works. It does not work just if I comment the QMessageBox, which is strange.

Comment: I think you question may be moved to another stackoverflow space: https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok, it was moved. Thank you.